# VBA to test the speed of another program

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 competing programs for a project I am working on. It is a change management tracking tool. It uses the `application.undo` function.

I'm trying to write a 3rd program to do changes so I can get data on which program runs faster, however, the `application.undo` does not work with the programs.

Any idea on how to bypass this or a work around?

```
Sub Counter()
     Dim i As Integer
     Worksheets("F&E List").Cells(6, 6).Value = 0
     For i = 1 To 5
         Worksheets("F&E List").Cells(6, 6).Value = i
         Application.Undo
     Next i
End Sub
```

This gives me run time 1004 "Method Undo of object'_Application failed"

Which is the same error I get from the general program

Comment: We need more details to give a meaningful answer.

Comment: Is the other program also Excel/VBA?  How huge & how slow **is** this change management tool that you need to develop an application **just to test it**?

Comment: It runs pretty smooth, depending on the level of changes the program takes about 0.40 seconds to run now. I am trying to increase my user experience by improving the code's performance. So I am modifying the algorithms and want to use a t test to compare sample data run times, hence the need for an independent program to run the samples for comparison.

Comment: How about a MCVE, there is way too much code for just the simple question about application.undo.

Comment: @Luuklag, I tried to add a MCVE, let me know if it is sufficient.

Comment: actions carried out by vba are not capable of being undone as they don't write to the "undo" stack. You'll need a different solution - perhaps something that records mouse movements and keystrokes

Comment: Seems obvious but i have to ask...is there anyway to turn them on so that they write to the undo stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I adjusted the code to simulate the undo in both programs to test the rest of the code without actually initiating the application.undo command. I figured that undo time would be the same in both programs so it wouldn't be a factor in the speed of the code (at lease one I could control) but this way I could still compare the code.

This sub updates the spreadsheets and records how much time each iteration took, then exports to another sheet so I can look at it in minitab

```
 Sub Counter()
     Dim i As Integer
     Dim j As Integer
     Dim Time_Arr As Variant
     Worksheets("F&E List").Cells(4, 6).Value = 0
     ReDim Time_Arr(0) As Variant

     For i = 1 To 1000
         Worksheets("F&E List").Cells(4, 6).Value = i
         ReDim Preserve Time_Arr(i) As Variant
         Time_Arr(i) = Timer()
     Next i

     For i = 2 To UBound(Time_Arr)
         Worksheets("Time_Stamp").Cells(i, 1).Value = i
         Worksheets("Time_Stamp").Cells(i, 2).Value = Time_Arr(i) - Time_Arr(i - 1)
     Next i
 End Sub
```

This is the main body of the code, I have not included the sub-procedures, i can if anyone would like to look at them. Note how i bypassed the application.undo and created a fake old value. My goal now is to look into times at each step and how i can further reduce the processing time to reduce lag as this is needed on daily use of the table.

```
 Sub New_Process(Target As Range)

     Dim vStartTime As Variant
     Dim rng As Range
     Dim new_arr As Variant, old_arr As Variant, add_arr As Variant
     Dim add_val As String, r As Range
     Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

     On Error GoTo ErrHandler:

     Set rng = Intersect(Target, Range("FETable"))

     If rng Is Nothing Then
         Exit Sub
     End If

     Call Optimize_VBA

     new_arr = rng.Value
     add_val = rng.Address

     **'Application.Undo 'changed to a comment for testing purposes**

     **'old_arr = Range(add_val).Value**
     old_arr = -1

     Call Get_Add(add_arr, rng)

     Range(add_val).Value = new_arr

     If rng.Count = 1 Then

         If old_arr <> new_arr Then
             Call Check_Change(old_arr, new_arr, add_val)
         End If             
     Else
    For i = LBound(add_arr, 1) To UBound(add_arr, 1)
        For j = LBound(add_arr, 2) To UBound(add_arr, 2)
            If old_arr(i, j) <> new_arr(i, j) Then
                'Debug.Print i, j, add_arr(i, j), old_arr(i, j), new_arr(i, j)
                Call Check_Change(old_arr(i, j), new_arr(i, j), add_arr(i, j))
                 End If
             Next j
         Next i
     End If

     Call Return_Func

 ErrHandler:

     If Err.Number = 13 Then
         Call Return_Func
         Exit Sub
     End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: It would be nice to share the way you used to simulate this, as future reference to other that might have a similar problem.